# Passing a void pointer to an if condition

Tags: c, pointers, if-statement

As I know, In C ,

```
● A value of zero represents false.
● Any nonzero value represents true.
```

In the following code

```
void *counting_thread(void *c) 
{
  int i, *j; 
  if(c) j = c;
  else  j = &i;    

  ....

}
```

I am unable to understand how the void pointer is evaluated inside the if condition. How is the if condition is evaluated in the following two scenarios?

```
If c is a null pointer 
If c is not a null pointer
```

Answer (score 3):

Any pointer (object pointer, function pointer, void pointer) evaluated in a boolean context is `false` if it is null, and `true` otherwise.

Comment: Can you refer me to a book which explains this?

Comment: @DesirePRG You can read the C standard. The section titled "The if statement" says "...the first substatement is executed if the expression compares unequal to 0". So you know the test is meaning `if ( c != 0 )`. Then you look up the meaning of `!=` which is under "Equality operators". There it says "If one operand is a pointer and the other is a null pointer constant, the null pointer constant is converted to the type of the pointer.". And then "Two pointers compare equal iff both are null pointers...".

Comment: I'll add to this that the null pointer points to address 0 in most (all?) architectures. &null = 0 = false in an if statement.

Answer (score 1):

I think the following quotes from the C99 Standard will halp you.

> 6.3.1.2 Boolean type
>
> 1 When any scalar value is converted to _Bool, the result is 0 if the
>   value compares equal to 0; otherwise, the result is 1.59
>
> 6.8.4.1 The if statement Constraints
>
> 1 The controlling expression of an if statement shall have scalar
>   type.
>
> 2 In both forms, the first substatement is executed if the expression
>   compares unequal to 0.

So in this statement

```
if(c) j = c;
```

there is checked whether pointer c of type `void *` contains 0 or some non-zero value.

Consider the following program

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    void *p;
    int x = 10;

    p = NULL;

    if ( p ) puts( "p is not equal to 0" );
    else puts( "p is equal to 0" );

    p = &x;

    if ( p ) puts( "p is not equal to 0" );
    else puts( "p is equal to 0" );

    return 0;
}
```

The output will be

```
p is equal to 0
p is not equal to 0
```

Answer (score 0):

As Kerrek SB writes, a null pointer evaluates as false, all other pointers as true. Therefore, if `c` is the null pointer, `j` will be assigned the address of the local variable `i`. If `c` is not the null pointer, `j` will point to the memory `c` points to.

The intention of such construct is likely to provide a valid pointer for some code later on that requires a valid `int *` to write to, which may or may not have been provided by the caller of `counting_thread`.